# Why it draw no retangles on my JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Hi guys (Sorry for my poor English),

I'm busy making a exercise for school. I can't get the retangles draw on my JPanel... Anyone that see the problem in my code? I want it drawn on my right panel. BTW east is on the west and west is on the east. Thanks for the help :)!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;


public class P1027 extends JFrame {

private JButton button;
private JTextField field;
private JPanel east;
private JPanel west;
//static Graphics g;

public P1027() {

    init();

}

public void init() {

    final int FRAME_WIDHT = 800;
    final int FRMAE_HEIGHT = 1000;
    int input = 3;

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDHT, FRAME_WIDHT);
    frame.setTitle("Frame");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    west = new JPanel();
    west.setSize(600, 900);
    west.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

    east = new JPanel();
    button = new JButton("Add squares");

    button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jt1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }

        public void jt1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

            //int aantalRect = Integer.parseInt(field.getText());
            MyDrawing draw = new MyDrawing();
            east.add(draw);
            System.out.println("hoi");

        }
    });

    field = new JTextField(5);
    east.add(button);
    east.add(field);
    east.setSize(300, 1000);
    button.setSize(100, 50);

    east.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

    frame.add(east);
    frame.add(west);

    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] a) {

    P1027 form = new P1027();

}

}

class MyDrawing extends JComponent {

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(25, 25, 100, 100);

    g.drawRect(50, 100, 50, 50);
    g.drawRect(300, 150, 100, 50);

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problems:

- After adding a component (the `MyDrawing` JComponent) to a container (the east JPanel), you should call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` for the container to layout the added component and to redraw itself, cleaning up any "dirty" pixels.
- Your `MyDrawing` JComponent has a preferredSize of [0, 0], and so when you add it to a FlowLayout-using container, it's likely going to stay [0, 0]. You will want to either override its `getPreferredSize()` method (preferred per Kleopatra) or set its preferredSize.

Comment: @Tony: no, try it yourself please. This is not a "do my code for me service" but a question answer service.

Comment: Oke i got that. Thanks. Now i want to declare that the rectangles only draws on that specific JPanel..